# Is there a way to change the Delivery Mode in PublishJMS processor in Nifi?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, apache-nifi

​I am sending messages to IBM MQ using Nifi PublishJMS processor. The Messages have Persistence = Persistent in MQ. I want to change it to Non-Persistent. Is there a property in Nifi PublishJms processor to correct this? Or is it done from the MQ side. I don't have access to MQ servers, I can only check the messages being delivered to the queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a low level a MQ client applications can specify the following persistence values:

- `MQPER_PERSISTENCE_AS_PARENT` (Use the value of the next topic above this one)
- `MQPER_NOT_PERSISTENT` (self-explanatory)
- `MQPER_PERSISTENT` (self-explanatory)
- `MQPER_PERSISTENCE_AS_TOPIC_DEF` (Use the value of this topic, the default on a topic is ASPARENT so this works like `MQPER_PERSISTENCE_AS_PARENT` where defaults are in use)

If nothing is specified then `MQPER_PERSISTENCE_AS_TOPIC_DEF` is the default.

Within the JMS API you can override this using a URI property as follows:

`queue:///theQueueName?persistence=1`

---

Property `persistence` and all URI properties are documented in the IBM MQ v8 Knowledge center page "[Creating destinations in a JMS application](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032240_.htm)".

**Property name:** persistence

> - `-2` - As specified on the send() call or, if not specified on the send() call, the default persistence of the message producer.
> - `-1` - As specified by the DefPersistence attribute of the IBM MQ queue or topic.
> - `1` - Nonpersistent.
> - `2` - Persistent.
> - `3` - Equivalent to the value HIGH for the PERSISTENCE property as used in the IBM MQ JMS administration tool. For an explanation of this
>     value, see [JMS persistent
>     messages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032380_.htm?view=kc#q032380_).

Comment: Thanks, overriding the URI worked for me. Also thanks for the description.